# get count from Kendo UI dataset

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have the following code and I am trying to get the count of returned records *without* having to issue a second fetch() command:

```
dsOffers = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: PRODUCTAPI,
            data: getOfferData()
        }
    },
    serverPaging: true,
    pageSize: 50,
    schema: {
        data: "results",
        total: "count",
        model: { id: "id" }
    }
})
.bind("error", namespace.dataSource_error);

dsOffers.total(); // returns 0

// if I use this, my API is hit twice
dsOffers.fetch(function() {
    console.log(dsOffers.total()); // returns 3
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it takes time loading the data (it happens asynchronously -in background/parallel-). If you print it just after the initialization you actually don't have the data available.

This is the correct behaviour.

If you don't want to do the *second* fetch you should print it in the `dataBound` event.

Comment: Ah.  The dreaded asynchronous ajax gremlin.  Gets me every time.  I will rework my code and update.